# Regex for number matching optional with whitespace and character?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

Hi  I am very new to regex and I am trying to generate the regex which will match the exact 19 characters which will be contain either of (White space,character'O' and numeric from 0-9) any one of these combination like "000 32 493O9O 11007" i have triad varais option but didn't worked any help will be good.

Comment: Will you accept 19 times O or 19 times spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[O0-9 ]{19}
```

(there is a space between the `[O0-9` and the `]`)

example http://regexr.com?35r1c

Probably it's better to anchor at the beginning and end of the string

```
^[O0-9 ]{19}$
```

example http://regexr.com?35r1f

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use the character class:

```
[0-9O ]{19}
```

You may want to include start / end anchors (`^` / `$`) to disallow any characters other than this:

```
^[0-9O ]{19}$
```

Comment: i don't want all the characters only "O" with the numeric values and white spaces so adding the character class will also allow the other characters ?

Comment: @user2553512 The character class will only match those characters but without the start / end anchors this would allow other characters before or after, e.g. `"---000 32 493O9O 11007---"`.